# Zenoss - file systems utilization showing "Unknown"

Tags: filesystems, monitoring, zenoss

All of a sudden, I've noticed that all devices are showing "Unknown", under **Components** - **File Systems** - **%Util** column.

I've tried modeling the device, but that doesn't resolve the issue. I found that deleting and re-adding the device does solve the issue, but I'd like to know if anyone else experienced this issue and if there is a better way of correcting the issue, without deleting and re-adding the device.

Using `zenoss-4.2.3-1695.el6.x86_64`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ZenModel/FileSystem.py:

```
def capacity(self):
    """
    Return the percentage capacity of a filesystems using its rrd file.
    Calculate using available blocks instead used blocks to account for
    reserved blocks.
    """
    __pychecker__='no-returnvalues'
    totalBlocks = self.getTotalBlocks()
    availBlocks = self.availBlocks()
    if totalBlocks and availBlocks is not None:
        return round(100.0 * (totalBlocks - availBlocks) / totalBlocks)
    return 'unknown
```

=> *totalBlocks* or *availBlocks* is None in your case. Check which one and then investigate why (for example: zenperfsnmp run -d  -v 10)?

Answer (score 0):

I see this if for some reason the connection is broken during a perfomanace data collection. To get back the correct values you have to (re)model the device and wait until the next performance data will be collected (normally 5min.) Observed this only against devices which are monitored via SNMP. //Arthur

Comment: You can add some links to support your answer